# see all active virtual hosts in nginx?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost

In apache2, I can see all the active virtual hosts by doing `apache2ctl -S`. This is useful since I don't need to plough through the config files, and also if I have made changes to the config files and not yet restarted apache2.

Is there an equivalent function in nginx?

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, nginx doesn't have the equivalent of apache2ctl -S.